# Get Email ID or Name from AMPscript

Tags: email, exacttarget, ampscript

I'm new to exacttarget and ampscript so I'm sorry if this is trivial. I've tried searching the help documentation to no avail.

I'd like to include the email name or ID as metadata in an email.

Is there a way to retrieve this information at send time to include in the email?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes!  There's a personalization variable for that.

Inside an AMPScript block you can reference it with: `emailName_`

Outside an AMPScript block you can reference it like this: `%%emailName_%%`

More info here: [**Personalization Strings**](https://ampscript.guide/system-strings/)

Comment: New URL for this information: http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/strings/